# Team Foundation 2010 - Work Item Custom Controls asking for assembly Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls, Version=8.0.0.0

Tags: user-controls, customization, extensibility, workitem

I tried creating my own work item custom control, but without success.
I thought it was something in my code, so I downloaded the custom work item controls from codeplex. Didn't work.

I'm getting a weird error...

For instance, when trying to add a CheckBox control:

Failed to load WorkItemCheckBox control. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The project references are all correct

I'm using Team Foundation 2010

I checked PrivateAssemblies folder

Also checked the GAC

Why the hell does it look for version 8.0 instead of 10.0 ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was likely compiled against a previous version of TFS.

This post might help you fix it

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/tfsworkitemtracking/thread/7e6ee51f-31f9-4859-8e9b-e081400576d7